# List of different types in C# (Inventory system)

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, inventory, inventory-management

So, I'm building an inventory system in Unity3D using C# from scratch and I've faced the following problem:

I have three types of inventory objects:

**Weapons, Equipments and Consumables.**

So, for example:

```
// Weapon Class
class Weapon : Equipable
{
    public int damage
}

// Equipment Class
class Equipment : Equipable
{

    public EquipmentType equipmentType;

    public enum EquipmentType {
        Helmet,
        Armor
    }
}    

// Consumable Class
class Consumable : Item
{
    public ConsumableStat stat;
    public int factor;

    public enum ConsumableStat
    {
        Life,
        Mana
    }
}

// Equipable Class
class Equipable : Item
{
    public int durability
}

// Item Class
class Item
{
    public string name;
}
```

Now, player has a list as an inventory.

This list, should store **Weapons, Equipments and Consumables**

I've tried:

```
public List<T> inventory
```

But I receive the following error on console:

**The type or namespace name `T' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

Have searched the internet but found solutions that I don't think it's the most correct way to deal with it.

Someone already step in this issue?

What's the best way to really create a list of Generic Objects?

C# and Unity3D is new for me. I'm a experienced web developer migrating to gaming development.

Ps.: Sorry for the poor English and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a type when setting a list on a class, i.e. your `public List<T> Inventory` - in order to store all of these things in a single list, they need to have a common type or interface shared across them. I suggest either creating a shared interface or a base type. In this specific case, I think a base type makes the most sense. For Example:

```
public abstract Item
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    bool IsConsumable { get; }
    /* etc. or whatever you use in all your classes */
{
```

This way you can build your inventory list this way:

```
public List<Item> Inventory;
```

Whether or not that meets your needs, the issue you are running into is that you can't define a list that isn't of a type, and you need a shared base type across all your inventory items so that you can create a list of the lowest common denominator. Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh Gosh! I've already did this and doesn't work. For some reason. Now I'm too afraid to ask why. lol After a good clean up on my code I've tried and it works. As my objects inherit from Item. Creating a List<Item> solved the problem.

Thanks @tophallen!